# GAE - Is there a setParameters counterpart to declareParameters for Datastore queries?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the [Datastore Queries documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries) an example can be seen of the query being set using the Query object method calls:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Person.class);
q.setFilter("lastName == lastNameParam");
q.setOrdering("height desc");
q.declareParameters("String lastNameParam");
List<Person> results = (List<Person>) q.execute("Smith");
```

I like this style because it makes each part readable and easy to understand what is being done. However, at the end they pass in the value "Smith" for the "lastNameParam" during the actual `execute` line. From my point of view, to be consistent there should be a `setParameters` Query method so that the values being passed to the parameters are clearly stated in the same way the the parameter names are declared. I haven't been able to find such a method for Query. Does one exist? If not, is there a good reason why not? Or am I being silly in my thinking and my reasoning is unfounded? Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an existing way to do this. The function `setParameter()` is available. For example, the code from the question could be done in the following way:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Person.class);
q.setFilter("lastName == lastNameParam");
q.setOrdering("height desc");
q.declareParameters("String lastNameParam");
q.setParameter("lastNameParam", "Smith");
List<Person> results = (List<Person>) q.execute();
```

I may have framed the original question badly as this is has little to do with Google App Engine or Google Datastore and mostly involves Java's Query class. In any case, this is the working solution.